# How to show data from table columns in the view

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a "Question and Answer" section and I would like to show it on the user's profile (recipient_id) if the answer is not NULL.

Ex.

```
Q: How many letters are in the word 'red'?
A: It has 3 letters.
```

I don't know how to add to the view so that visitors can view that user's Q&A section like the example.

Answers controller:

```
def new
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
end

def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
    redirect_to questions_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Questions controller:

```
def index
  @questions = Question.all
  respond_with(@questions)
end

def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @questions = Question.order("created_at DESC")
  respond_with(@questions)
end

def new
  @question = Question.new
  respond_with(@question)
end

def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  if @question.save
    @message = Message.create(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
      :sender_id => @question.sender_id,
      :recipient_id => @question.recipient_id,
      :body => @question.question)

    @question.message = @message
    @question.save
    redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
  else
    render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
  end
end

def update
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @question.update_attributes(:answer => params[:question][:answer])
  redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox => "inbox")
end
end
```

User Profile view:

```
<h5>SHOW QUESTIONS & ANSWERS</H5>
<%= render :partial => "answers/show", :locals => { :question => @question} %>
```

Schema for Q&A:

```
create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "question"
  t.string   "answer"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.integer  "sender_id"
  t.integer  "recipient_id"
  t.integer  "message_id"
end
```

Questions model:

```
  attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id

  belongs_to :sender,
        :class_name => 'User',
        :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
        belongs_to :recipient,
        :class_name => 'User',
        :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

        belongs_to :message

end
```

Users Controller:

```
def settings
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def profile
  @profile = User.profile
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @question = User.find(params[:recipient_id])
  @letsgos = @user.letsgos.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @letsgo = current_user.letsgos.build
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def destroy
  User.find(id_params).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted."
  redirect_to users_url
end

def update
  @user = if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
            User.find(params[:id])
          else
            current_user
          end
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  respond_with @user
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :username, :password, :ethnicity, :gender, :zip_code, :birthday, :role, :age, :sexuality)
end
```

Comment: No answer, but some ideas. 1) If you want to see what's in your `@answers` instance variable in the view, you can use `<%= debug @answers %>` which will output it's contents yaml format. 2) Your `AnswersController` could be cleaned up with a `before_action :load_question` which finds and sets `@question` for each action (or only the ones you wish) on the `AnswersController`.

Comment: Can we see the schema for your `questions` and `answers` tables?

Comment: @kristinalim schema was added. There is only a questions table, no answer.

Comment: @Thomas Klemm thanks for the tips. I debug it previously. Shows only dashes.

Comment: @xps15z i think you should read this article about debugging your rails application http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: The issue is not to debug. I don't have it setup properly to extract the Q&A from the table so I can display in the view.

Comment: The debugging article is a good read, I recommend you to read that as it can be helpful in the future. I decided to assist you with your question. GL

Comment: Could you post the user controller action that goes with your User Profile view please?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here. What exactly are you trying to do? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @carolclarinet I added the users controller.

Comment: @Roganartu I am trying to output the Q&A that has been assign to the user. If I go on users 18 profile page it should show every question they have answered on their profile.

Comment: @xps15z ok, what does `User.profile` do?

Comment: The thing is you're trying to render `@question` in your profile view, but you're not setting that in your `UsersController#profile` action that I can tell. In fact, it doesn't look like you're getting a `User` instance in `UsersController#profile`, and I would expect you to have that given what you are trying to do.

Comment: @carolclarinet I have under def show in the users controller `@question = User.find(params[:recipient_id])` and I have tried several other methods.

Comment: Setting instance variables in one controller action does not set it for any other action. Also, why are you setting `@question` to an instance of `User`? Don't you want to be looking up a `Question` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to show that users Q&A based on the provided recipient_id. If that is the case try this...

For Users controller replace @question with:

```
@question = Question.where(recipient_id: params[:id])
```

In your view where you want to show the Q&A on user profile:

```
<% @question.select(&:answer?).each do |question| %>
Question: <%= question.question %><br>
Answer: <%= question.answer %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

This will load so that if the user did not supply a answer it will not show on their page. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Its simply You can use [ActiveRecordAssociation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations) to solve the issue and complexity of your coding structure.

```
#app/models/Question.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :answer

#app/models/Answer.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :question

#app/models/user.rb
has_many :questions
has_many :answers


#controller/users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.answers
    @questions = current_user.answers.collect{|x|x.question}        
  end
end

#app/view/user/1/show   like ur '**user's profile page**'
<% if @questions.present?%>
  <%= @questions.each do |question| %>      
     <%= question.title %>
     <%= question.answer.body %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

i hope it will work for you any queries share it.
'**current_user**' is a helper method use '**session**'

Comment: for each question have more than one(including wrong answer) answer that so, i used relation ship for **questions has_many answers **

Comment: I do not have a Answers model. So I am not sure why you're writing code based around me having one. I apologize for any confusion. I have my schema posted so `question.title` should be just `question.question` and `question.answer.body` should be `question.answer`. I don't have a title or body column. The "title" of the question would be under the `question` column. The "body" of the question would be under the `answer` column. Making those changes I get a `undefined method 'question'` that's for def show `if @user.question`

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things that I don't understand why you're doing them in your code, so you may need to modify this to suit your purposes, but this is what I think you want.

I'm assuming your "user profile page" is a page you reach by going to a route like `/users/profile/:id`, and that that route goes to your `UsersController#profile` action. If this is not what you have, you will need to modify your routes to use my code.

Then in your `UsersController`:

```
def profile
  # First get the user whose profile you are trying to show
  # If you do not get an :id that is the User's ID in `params`, you will need 
  # to change your routes.
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  # Now get the question that has this user as its recipient_id 
  @question = Question.where(recipient_id: params[:id]).first
end
```

And now your Users profile view that you mention above that I'm assuming is in `app/views/users/profile.html.erb` can use `@question` like you have it:

```
<h5>SHOW QUESTIONS & ANSWERS</H5>
<%= render :partial => "answers/show", :locals => { :question => @question} %>
```

Again, if this code does not work, it is likely that there are incorrect assumptions that I have made about how your application is set up, so you will need to understand what Rails does and how that relates to what you are trying to do. Read any error messages you get and fix what they are telling you is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I understand the def profile but that is not working. I have tried the examples here, created my own code, and tweak the examples here and nothing has worked unfortunately. I have a Q&A feature. A user can be asked a question by another user. The question will show in the Questions table under `question`. When the user answers it their response will appear under `answer`. The table records the `sender_id` and `recipient_id`. The params should be collecting the current user_id and recipient_id (ex: user 78 profile will show Q&A that has recipient_id of 78).

Comment: I forgot to mention no error is being produce on the page. The Q&A section remains blank as it was doing before.

Comment: I suggest looking in your logs to see what queries are being done and to see why they're not returning the data from your database that you expect.

Comment: I used your def for @questions and changed the view so that it's `<%= @question.each do |question| %>
         <%= question.question%>
         <%= question.answer%>
    <% end %>` I have to make changes so that it doesn't show Questions where the answer is NULL and it's also outputting the entire table data at the bottom of the page. So all the Q&A's show and then at the bottom of the page it has everything inside brackets with the created_at, updated_at, sender_id, etc information. That bottom part shouldn't be showing at all so I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you could solve your problem with some [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations) on the different models, to allow you to pull the questions & answers for specific users:

```
#app/models/User.rb
has_many :questions, :class_name => 'User'
has_many :answers, :class_name => 'Answer', :through => :question #-> probably won't work right

#app/models/Question.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :answer

#app/models/Answer.rb
belongs_to :user
has_one :question
```

I'd need to tweak these associations to get them to work properly (both because your question was a little fuzzy, and you didn't post any model code), but I hope this will give you an idea of what you can do:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def index #the page you're using to display the questions & answers
    @user = User.find(params[:recipient_id])
end

#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<%= @user.questions.each do |question| %>
    <% if defined?(question.answer) %>
         <%= question.title %>
         <%= question.answer.body %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

It seems you're mixing your controllers & views, when really, I would just focus on the `users` controller and get all the data funnel through the models. Rails conventions encourage "[fat model, skinny controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/)", which means you should really just use the controller to ping different models, and let them deal with the logic

Comment: I never added the modes because what I had in the Question model didn't seem relevant. I will post what I have inside of it. There's no Answers model. I have it setup so that the users Answer is posted inside the Questions table with its own column.

Comment: With the code I do get a `couldn't find user without an id` error.